# Strongly typed List created with wrongly typed data

Tags: java, arraylist, typed

I have a strongly typed List  `Arraylist<Byte>` and a developer was trying to add primitive byte data, but the result was completely unexpected.  A `byte[]` was added to this list; how is this even possible?  Here is a short example that demonstrates the issue in Java 7

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Byte> wrappedBytes;
    byte[] primitiveBytes = new byte[] { (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03 };

    wrappedBytes = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(primitiveBytes));

    Object value1 = wrappedBytes.get(0);
    System.out.println(value1.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

The system says the first value is a `byte[]` but the list should only contain `Byte` values.

Comment: what about warnings?  ArrayList is a raw type

Answer (score 2):

You created a raw `ArrayList`, then assigned it to an `ArrayList<Byte>`.  You should have received a warning when you compiled this code about an unchecked assignment, and a warning about calling a raw `ArrayList` constructor given the typed return from `Arrays.asList`.

Because of this, you wind up creating a `List<byte[]>`, creating a raw `ArrayList` with it, and assigning it to an `ArrayList<Byte>`.  This only fails to create a `ClassCastException` because you assigned the return of `get(0)` to an `Object`.

The reason it's a `List<byte[]>` is that a `List<byte>` isn't possible, because primitive types aren't allowed as generic type parameters, and [`Arrays.asList(T... a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) is a generic method.  The only inference is `List<byte[]>`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.asList expects an array of objects (T... obj) as its arguments. The only object you have here is the byte[], hence you get `List<byte[]>`.

Try

```
Byte[] primitiveBytes = new Byte[]{...};
```

To complete, this

```
wrappedBytes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(primitiveBytes));
```

would fail when compiled with a byte[] and has no warning when compiled with Byte[].